# Under AIX, how can I get the full path of a program bound to a port?

Tags: process, aix, socket, lsof, netstat

Under Linux I can use `netstat -tulpnw` and `ps`, like so:

```
# netstat -tulpnw | grep :53
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1482/named          
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53                0.0.0.0:*                               1482/named          

# ps aux | fgrep 1482
named     1482  0.0  1.0  93656 44900 ?        Ssl  Sep06   3:17 /usr/sbin/named -u named
root     20221  0.0  0.0   4144   552 pts/0    R+   21:09   0:00 fgrep --color=auto 1482
#
```

How can I get the full path of a program bound to a port when using `ksh` in AIX 6?

Answer (score 10):

As [recommended by IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-lsof.html): use `lsof -i -n` and look for port XY. If you want parseable output from `lsof`, use the `-F` flag and parse the output with awk.

You can get [pre-compiled binaries for AIX V5](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/wikis/display/WikiPtype/AIXV53lsof). I don't know if there are pre-compiled binaries for V6; if there aren't, get the [source](http://people.freebsd.org/~abe/) and compile it.

Comment: lsof is not always available on AIX:P

Comment: So [Download it](http://ftp.unicamp.br/pub/unix-tools/lsof/binaries/aix/) or compile it from [source](http://people.freebsd.org/~abe/), it's [recommended by IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-lsof.html).

Comment: there aren't always "lsof" on the machines... but i could take this as a good answer (other ones are "good" too! ty)

Answer (score 4):

Try using `netstat` with `rmsock`.

```
port=$1
addr=`netstat -Aan | grep $port | awk '{print $1}`
pid=`rmsock $addr tcpcb | awk '{print $9}'`
ps -ef | grep $pid
```

For `netstat`, the `-A` shows the address of any protocol control blocks associated with the sockets, the `-a` option shows the state of all sockets including those of server processes, and the `-n` option gives output in numeric form, so you're not wasting time trying to resolve addresses.

`rmsock`, using the address given in the column1 output of `netstat`, and using the `tcpcb` database, will return information about the process holding that socket, including the pid and name.

You can then use `ps -ef | grep $pid` to get the process information.

You can see [this article](http://www.ibmsystemsmag.com/aix/tipstechniques/systemsmanagement/AIX-TCP-IP-Utilities-for-Sockets-to-Process-ID-Map/) at IBM Systems Magazine for more info on this.

Comment: this is not event executing correctly on my AIX

Answer (score 1):

One of the quickest way to find the application locking port is to use *lsof* or *lsof64*:

```
lsof64 -nP | grep $PortNumber
```

or

```
lsof -nP | grep $PortNumber
```

Above will return process ID locking/using given port number. Once you have it then run below to find running application/process

```
proctree $pid
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with AIX, but have you tried the `w` or `e` formatting arguments to `ps`?

```
ps uwx | grep 1482
# or 
ps uex | grep 1482
```

Comment: You can check the [manual](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/topic/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds4/ps.htm) online. AIX `ps` does support traditional BSD flags, but how do the flags you indicated help?

Comment: Hm, looks like they do different things on AIX. Although the documentation you referenced includes an l option which prints "USER, PID, %CPU, %MEM, SZ, RSS, TTY, STAT, STIME, TIME, and COMMAND fields"

Answer (score 0):

```
netstat -ape | grep $PortNumber
```

Comment: Could you explain what the command is doing? Pasting code without justification isn't very helpful.